# Send notification when the network route changes

Tags: networking, notification, systemd-resolved

I have 2 network interfaces:

- ethernet `enp2s0` with default `metric 1`
- mobile `enx0` with default `metric 2`

When Ethernet goes down, the metric changes and vice versa. I am getting in systems notifications something like this:

```
systemd-resolved[628]: enp2s0: Bus client set default route setting: no
systemd-resolved[628]: enx0: Bus client set default route setting: yes
```

When the Ethernet connection is restored, it changes back:

```
systemd-resolved[628]: enp2s0: Bus client set default route setting: yes
systemd-resolved[628]: enx0: Bus client set default route setting: no
```

I have Ubuntu SystemD, and I have self-written script to send any notifications via one of public messengers, so in my case there will be 2 scenarios:

1. `send_messenger.sh "me" "the traffic is routed through 4g connection from now, please, be patient"` when Ethernet is down and the modem enabled
2. `send_messenger.sh "me" "ethernet is back, the normal bandwidth is available"` when Ethernet goes back.

What may be a `systemd` service which may trigger that script when the default route changes? Or one of the network interfaces is disconnected?

Comment: Did you try [monitoring DBus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2261815/4970442)? [This example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28183/209677) might be useful

Comment: Thanks! A bit complicated... I thought about unit services, but need more help in configuring...

Comment: I've written a bash script to help with this: `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic` It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect. You're welcome to adapt as needed.

Comment: Would that be possible to ask you to explain, how to use this script? Is it possible to run it as a service?
In my case, I would like to make that changeі of the route, specifically:
- when eth0 is down and 4g modem is enabled
- when eth0 is on again
will call my script (will send notificationі to admins).